# Deferring dynamically added Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to load some Javascript dynamically after the page has loaded.

Something like this:

- page loads
- page adds script element with `src = "file1.js"`
- page adds script element with `src = "file2.js"`

`file2.js` has a dependency on `file1.js` - it adds properties to an object defined in `file1.js`

The problem is that `file2.js` is loading first (because it is smaller), and is immediately throwing an error because its dependency doesn't exist.

Is there a way for me to defer evaluation/execution of these new scripts until they have all loaded. (There is actually more than two scripts)

If I were to just embed these scripts in a page normally in authored HTML, then it seems that the browser loads all scripts, then evaluates them. But it is behaving differently because I'm adding script elements on the fly.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a library like jQuery, or just plain javascript?

Comment: If you're willing to dive a little deeper into Script loading I'd highly recommend having a look at require.js

Comment: How are you inserting the script? You probably just need to hook into the `onload` event of the `script`.

Comment: Thanks for comments. The situation is that I have a web app which is working fine - there are several Javascript files that have dependencies on each other, but the browser seems to handle aysnchronous loading of these just fine. Now the requirement is to inject my app into a prior landing page. I can do this using an XHR and copying the head and body elements from one DOM tree to another. It's just the Javascript files which are behaving differently. I will look at RequireJS if I need to, but wondered if there was a magic setting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a library called RequireJS that handles exactly this situation, and handles every situation you never realized were problems - http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Answer (score 1):

Can't you wrap the contents of the files in functions and call them after everything has loaded?

Comment: Yes - a good idea, but I was looking for something more portable. i.e. I wanted to reuse all the same code whether it was standalone or injected

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions for you:

1. Have a look at http://requirejs.org/ It solves this problem, among
   others.
2. Or, roll your own simple js loader function. It would be a function that
   uses ajax to load a script and then calls a callback when it's done.
   Call this loader function in a nested way so that you load your
   scripts in the right order.